# git pull not copying a new directory on my master git repo

Tags: git

I have a local version of a git repo that I push to bitbucket and then pull to my server. I added some files locally, they made it to bitbucket on push, but when I do a...

```
git pull origin master
```

It is not pulling the new directory, even though it says my server copy is already up-to-date. Git works smoothly 90% of the time, but sometimes something like this happens and I cannot figure out what is going on.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the directory empty? Git doesn't track directories, only files.

Comment: I don't know if it counts as empty...the new directory is /newdir/newdir1/file.css

Comment: Moreover, if you try to stage the empty directory you can't so it should be an advertise that it won't work

Comment: I am experiencing similar oddity. A teammate has pushed a new directory with several files to Gitlab and I can see them in SourceTree, but I cannot get it to pull the new directory to my local repo. Claiming everything is up-to-date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still do not know what happened here, but I needed to restructure my repo a bit anyway since I set it up incorrectly in the beginning. I ended up making a new repo and everything has been smooth since then...

Answer (score 0):

Git ignores empty directories. Place a dummy file in your directory and try again. I think this is a common (ugly) practice.

Comment: I don't know if it counts as empty...the new directory is /newdir/newdir1/file.css

Comment: I `file.css` is a file the directory is not empty. `file.css` can have no content.

Comment: have you staged and commited this new file.css? I'll bet that you didn't. Try it and after that, do pull. Probably next time you clone the repo the new directory with file.css will appear

Comment: file.css is definitely there and it is not empty

Comment: @Facepalmed, staging meaning 'git add -A :/' and 'git commit'? I did that already and I even renamed it staged/committed, and then named it back to the original in an attempt to get it to click

Answer (score 0):

Does specified directory with file visible in "source" on bitbucket? I see some probably missed trivial things:

- "git push" for your local copy. Probably you missed it. Have you tried to checout in anorher directory? Will you changes exist there?
- another branch. Is it possible you've created new branch and committed your changes in it?

Comment: yes, file is visible in source on bitbucket, I did push the local copy. I did commit the changes in another branch, but that branch has since been merged and deleted